# Not seeing echo in stdout 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

Assembly noob here. 
I'm not getting any stdout from the echo.

```
mov ah, 01h   ;
int 21h       ;
```

When I do file redirection

program.asm < input > output

The only thing that is outputted is what I what I explicitly define to print.
But when I run my program with no file redirection, I see everything that I type with no issues.

I'm emulating DOSBox.

Any ideas on what could be causing the echo to not happen?

Comment: Given that `int` goes into the operating system, this would be best diagnosed if you included your OS in the question.

Comment: Added to question, emulating DOSBox

Comment: It seems like DOSBox doesn't support echoing with 01h. Although I'm not sure why. I've been told to just use 08h to read and 02h to echo if I want stdout to work with file redirection.

Comment: It's also worth noting that DOS knows absolutely zero about Unicode, so be careful when saving text files from GUI apps to save in the plainest ASCII possible (windows Unicode is typically encoded in ucs-2 and is two bytes per char, so typical text will be sprinkled with zeroes).

Answer (score 1):

My BIOS/DOS reference tells the following about DOS function 01h.
The name "**Keyboard***InputWithEcho*" somewhat hints the upcoming problems!

> When STDIN and STDOUT are redirected, problems can occur when using this function:
>
> - If input is coming from a file, a zero byte that does not correspond to an extended keyboard code may be returned.
> - The function can not detect the end of a file in DOS versions before V4.
>
> These considerations may cause significant problems when STDIN has been redirected so that input is retrieved from a file. Because of this you may want to use a different DOS input function: 06h, 07h, 08h, or 3Fh (when using handle 0, STDIN).

Since you are using both kinds of redirection (*program.asm < input > output*) it would be best to start using the DOS function 08h. It offers the closest match to function 01h. The fact that **it does not echo** should not matter since you want your output redirected to a file anyway.
If need be, then use function 02h to display each character on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **print** a character in the console you need to use the DOS call `02h` and set the ASCII code you want to print in `DL` register:

Example:

```
mov ah,02h
mov dl,41h
int 21h
```